Distributing books to children such that everyone has at least one book.
5 books are to be distributed to 4 children such that every child has at least one book. Find out the number of ways of doing this.

My approach:
Since each child gets at least one book so I will choose 4 books by $^5C_4$ and distribute them to 4 children by $4!$. Now only one book is left so I give it to any one of the children (4 ways).
So, $^5C_4\times4!\times4=480$, but the answer is $\boxed{240}$
Where have I gone wrong?

You can't tell which book was the extra one and which was handed to that child in the first four. Thus you double count.

@lulu I choose 4 specific books, so the remaining one should be the extra one

Consider the final grouping $(1& 2, 3,4,5)$, so the first kid gets books $1& 2$ and so on.  You can get that arrangement in two different ways.  Either you first give out    $(1,3,4,5)$ and then give book $2$ to the first kid, or you first give out $(2,3,4,5)$ and then give book $1$ to the first kid. Thus you count each arrangement twice.

First, find the total number of ways to distribute the books among the children, without any restrictions. Each book has 4 options for an owner, so the answer so far is $4 ^ 5 = 1024$. now, remove the "bad" ways. These are ones where at least one child doesn't have a book. Use inclusion-exclusion for this.
Let's count the ways where one child doesn't get any books. There are 4 ways to choose the child that doesn't get the book. There are 5 books to distribute to the remaining 3 children. The number of ways to do this for one child is $3^5 = 243$ and since there are 4 children, the total for this case is $243 \cdot 4 = 972$.
Now, let's count how two children don't get any books. There are 6 ways to choose which 2 children do not receive a book. The remaining 5 books can be distributed among the remaining 2 children in $2^5 = 32$ ways. since there are six ways to choose the children who don't get a book, $32 \cdot 6 = 192$.
Now, for three children. There are 4 ways to choose which 3 children do not receive a book. The remaining 5 books must go to the 1 remaining child, which can happen in only 1 way (all books go to that child, since $1^5=1$), and since there were 4 ways, $4 \cdot 1 = 4$.
Now, using inclusion-exclusion, $1024 - 972 + 192 - 4 = 240$.
your answer is exactly twice the real answer because you're counting everything twice: say the kid $i$ got the two books, named $n$ and $k$. one time, they got $n$ as the first book and $k$ as the second book, and another time, they got $k$ as the first book and $n$ as the second book. but it's the same thing, that kid is always getting $n$ and $k$, so your answer is twice the real answer. your approach wasn't incorrect, you just forgot to divide it by two.

Of course this question can be done in many methods, but I want to know whats wrong in my method.

@ADITYADAS  just edited my answer, it should answer your question.

I got it now, thanks

Elaborating on the comment of lulu, the original poster's method is wrong only because of the double counting.  This explains why the original poster's computation is exactly double the right answer.
For illustrative purposes, consider the following scenario, where Child-1 receives Book-1 and Book-2, and Children 2, 3, and 4 receive Books 3, 4, and 5 respectively.
This single scenario is represented twice in the original poster's computation of
$$\binom{5}{4} \times 4! \times 4. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, the $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{4}~$ factor represents the number of ways of selecting those $~4~$ books that will be initially distributed.
In (1) above the $~4!~$ factor represents the number of ways of permuting the first $~4~$ books distributed.
In (1) above the $~4~$ factor represents the number of ways of selecting which child gets the $~5$-th book.
The only flaw in the above computation is that the order that the books are distributed is irrelevant.
When Child-1 Receives Book-1 and Book-2, this is counted twice.  It is counted once when Book-1 is one of the first $~4~$ books distributed, and Book-2 is the 5th book distributed.
The exact same distribution is also counted when Book-2 is one of the first $~4~$ books distributed, and Book-1 is the 5th book distributed.

The standard enumeration approach to such a problem is that there are
$$\binom{5}{2} = 10$$
ways of selecting which two books will be paired together and given to one of the $~4~$ people.
Then, those two books are (in effect) fused into one unit.
So, the $~5~$ books are now represented by $~4~$ units.
These $~4~$ units can be distributed in $~4!~$ ways among the $~4~$ children.
So, the result is the computation of
$$\binom{5}{2} \times 4!.$$
